# How to set up an Angular project so it starts as part of the Visual Studio 2022 window, not as a new console window

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2022

I have made a basic Angular project, and when I run the application, the app starts correctly, but I would like it to start as part of the Visual Studio 2022 window, if possible, not in the new cmd window.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7cGf.png)

I have tried searching for it on the web, but I didn't find anything useful.